# Converting Spark data frame to List of Bean class

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading from CSV file and creating a dataframe. The output that i want is a List. My dataframe looks like

```
+---------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|last_value           |processed_on           |notes                |
+---------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|2017-01-10 00:10:00.0|2017-10-09 08:32:33.689|2017-01-04,2017-05-09|
|2016-01-20 00:05:00.0|2017-10-09 08:33:18.567|2017-01-10,2017-01-20|
+---------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

I have a Bean class which will store one row output.

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
   private String last_value;
   private String proccessed_on;
   private String notes;

   public CheckPointEntity() {}

   public void setLastValue(String last_value)
       {this.last_value=last_value;}

   public String getLastValue(){return last_value;}

   public void setProccessedOn(String proccessed_on){
    this.proccessed_on=proccessed_on;
   }

   public String getProccessed(){
    return proccessed_on;
   }

   public void setNotes(String notes){
    this.notes=notes;
   }
   public String getNotes(){
    return notes;
   }
}
```

I am trying to convert the dataframe to List

```
Dataset<Row> df  = SparkSession.read()
            .format("csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .load("/tmp/somepath");;


df.map((MapFunction<Row, MyClass>)
                    Row -> setBean(
                            (String) Row.get(schemaVal.get("last_value")),
                            (String) Row.get(schemaVal.get("processed_on")),
                            (String) Row.get(schemaVal.get("notes"))
                    ),
            Encoders.bean(MyClass.class)
    ).collectAsList();
```

But i am getting error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.spark_project.guava.reflect.TypeToken.method(TypeToken.java:465)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$2.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:125)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.javaBean(ExpressionEncoder.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.bean(Encoders.scala:142)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.bean(Encoders.scala)
```

What is wrong here ? Should there be a different approach for doing it ?

Comment: what has written on` TypeToken.java` line number 465. and seems like row or column data may be empty so check for empty or null

Comment: I think this is happening because the getters and setters in the Bean class do not match the property names. Eg.: Getters and setters signatures for private String last_value; would be getLast_Value() and setLast_Value(String last_value). Please check.